# Power supply charging backup power - current flow via mosfet

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, battery-charging, backup

I have following [diagram on falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.634267539816555%2050%205%2050%0Aw%20288%20224%20400%20224%200%0Af%20288%20304%20400%20304%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20288%20224%20288%20304%200%0Ag%20400%20464%20400%20480%200%0A162%20400%20224%20400%20288%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0A162%20400%20400%20400%20464%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20400%20336%20400%20400%200%0Aw%20400%20320%20400%20336%200%0Af%20224%20384%20272%20384%2033%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20272%20400%20304%20400%200%0Aw%20304%20400%20400%20400%200%0Aw%20192%20384%20192%20304%200%0Aw%20192%20304%20288%20304%200%0AR%20224%20224%20192%20224%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%20272%20352%20224%20352%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0As%20224%20224%20288%20224%200%200%20false%0Ar%20400%20352%20272%20352%200%201000%0Aw%20272%20352%20272%20368%200%0Aw%20192%20384%20224%20384%200%0A)

[image]

Top +5V is main PSU (12V 10A). Bottom +5V is battery (12V 2.3Ah). I have load about 2-3A so I dont think diode is good solution. Well I am trying to achieve following: While PSU is plugged then run circuit from PSU and charge battery. When it comes to power outage I would like to run circuit from battery.

What is not working? I dont know if its falstad issue or not but while PSU is active there is no current flowing to battery via resistor. Also I forgot to mention if there is power outage on PSU I definitely not want to charge PSU from battery (thats why there is mosfet) because behind mosfet will be 2 resistors to measure voltage by IC to notify user there is power outage.

Comment: It’s your design. Pch is reverse biased on Vgs . You can edit Vdd,Vss and also gm or Beta of each device and Vt of each device with a “slider” or fixed value on Falstad. always assume your model is wrong in Falstad before blaming the physics in Falstad with known limitations on LED parameters which you can also change a model of a battery as 10kF + Vmin voltage source + ESR and reduce time sample to seconds vs us

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 ok. What should I do to fix it? Im bit new to mosfets

Comment: buy or use the IC model for the DW-01A. Your lower PFet is not ON since it is pulled high

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Its okay that PFet is off. It should be by design if NFet is ON. I just dont know why current is not flowing via resistor to another +5V (bottom - battery) to charge it

Comment: The switch on high side does not pull Pch gate to 0V when it Opens or PS is unplugged so add R gate to 0V

Comment: Oh. Youre right. Simply if I remove PFet then it should work right? When PFet is removed then current not flows through top.

Comment: I said add R gate to gnd not remove PFET but 1k and LEDs limit current so use DW-01A for LI ION and equiv cct for 12V Battery. Or look up Dual FET ideal diode switch for charging batteries

Comment: May I ask u for draw?

Comment: May I suggest you use DW01A instead

Comment: Is this for a small SLA or car battery? or LiPo or 3 Li Ion ? or what?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 12V Lead acid